# Add option to download Pdf in Gravity Forms directory plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I am using Gravity Forms directory plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-addons/ and i want to add option to download pdf when someone views entries.

I followed these steps by plugin support but my link is not showing in pdf. 
https://support.gravitypdf.com/t/how-to-add-the-pdf-download-link-to-the-gravity-forms-directory-front-end-list/341

The output is coming like this when i see it using inspect element.

```
<td class="text" title="PDF">&nbsp;</td>
```

I am using wordpress twenty sixteen theme (child version).

I will really appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

---

I ran into the same thing and had to create a workaround.

go to the file /wp-content/plugins/gravity-forms-addons/template-row.php

on line 250, add this code:

```
    if ($field_id == "9999999") {

    $template = 'default-template.php';

    $link = '<a href="' . site_url() . '/?gf_pdf=1&fid=' . $form_id . '&lid=' . $lead["id"] . '&template=' . $template . '&download=1">Download</a>';

    $value = $link;

    }
```

This should come just before the line that says "echo $value".

Assuming you follow the instructions in the link you posted, this should work.